# Strange activity on my computer, possibly hacking?

Tags: passwords, malware, exploit, google, desktop

So yesterday I got on my computer and changed my desktop, the next day I got on my computer and it froze so I rebooted it. But when I did my desktop background had changed and when I went on google and a ton of searches had shown up that I hadn't made and all of them looked like this "gdyfpazjexc -site:youtube.com"

Here is a screen shot of when I typed in the letter L
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I don't know what these searches are but they definitely have some red flags. And when my computer crashed when I got back on it was running really hard. Ill take some notes in the comments section. If anyone could help me that would be great thanks!
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: some room for clarification: (1.) "I got on my computer and changed my desktop" — changed your desktop *background*? … (2.) "But when I did my desktop background had changed" — changed to what? to an image that was already on your PC before this happened, or something you don't recognise? a screenshot would be nice.

Comment: Hello, the desktop image was already on my computer. And it was the default windows background

Comment: Is it possible that someone else is using your computer ( family, friends, etc ) ?

Comment: Nobody else used this computer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you have some malware on your computer which is performing something which is known as Blackhat SEO / SEO spam.

Search engine optimization is the process of making a page appear higher up on the page ranking when someone makes a search query.

Malicious SEO uses methods such as backlinks from hacked websites, performing automated requests from malware-infected PCS and other methods to attempt to trick Google's algorithm into ranking a page higher.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this means regarding the activity of your computer, but what you are seeing are Google searches done with the help of [Google Advanced Operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html).

*CTRL+F "-site" for the related entry :)*

They are not malicious in itself but I think there could be ways to abuse them.

In this particular sample, it looks like someone wanted to find a URL for "gdyfpazjexc" while ignoring all results from youtube.com. Could be a way for malicious software to find a link to it's host? Do you have more samples you could share?

Comment: This seems like a comment asking for clarification, not like an answer. The searches are obviously for youtube ids on sites that aren't youtube, but that doesn't really help the OP (who wants to know if their computer is hacked). The question seems on the verge of off-topic (too broad) to me, but an answer should at least try to explain why the behavior that the OP noticed might indicate - or might not indicate - a compromisation of their system.

Comment: I have more samples, there is around 40 or 50 searches I would estimate and they dont show up in my history.